# how to use 'cut' command in linux with multi character sting

Tags: linux, string, unix, cut

/home/user/views/links/user1/gitsrc/database/src/

This is my string. I want to cut it in 2 strings such as 
"/home/user/views/links/user1/"
"/database/src/"

so the delim is not actally a single character but a group of characters ie "gitsrc".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only define a single character as delimiter in `cut`.

You could use `awk` where the field separator can be a single character, a null string or a regular expression, e.g.

```bash
$ echo '/home/user/views/links/user1/gitsrc/database/src/' |
  awk -F'gitsrc' '{ print $1 " " $2 }'
/home/user/views/links/user1/ /database/src/
```

or

```bash
$ echo '/home/user/views/links/user1/gitsrc/database/src/' |
  awk -F'gitsrc' '{ print $1 ORS $2 }'
/home/user/views/links/user1/
/database/src/
```

---

In your shell you could or use a [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) to get the first and second part:

```bash
$ str=/home/user/views/links/user1/gitsrc/database/src/
$ echo "${str%%gitsrc*}"  # remove longest suffix `gitsrc*`
/home/user/views/links/user1/
$ echo "${str#*gitsrc}"   # remove shortest prefix `*gitsrc`
/database/src/
```